# Can I delete ReadyBoost Cache from main drive?

Tags: readyboost

When my laptop crashed, I took out the SSD, put it in an USB enclosure, and attached it to a loaner laptop. On the loaner I activated ReadyBoost, using the SSD as the external drive.

When it was time to put the SSD back in the original laptop, I should have used the settings to disable ReadyBoost first. I did not.

Now that the SSD is in the original laptop, I see it still has the ReadyBoost.sfcache file, taking up 33 GB of space.

Is there any danger in simply deleting ReadyBoost.sfcache from what is now my primary hard drive?

Comment: It's a cache file not being used by the system.  You cannot enable ReadyBoost on the system drive.

Comment: I don't want to use ReadyBoost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any danger in simply deleting ReadyBoost.sfcache from what is now my primary hard drive?

Since ReadyBoost is not currently active on the drive in question.  It is indeed safe to delete the unused cache file on the drive.